# Enable react-native new arch on iOS unconditionally

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

In https://reactnative.dev/docs/new-architecture-app-renderer-ios we see

`USE_FABRIC=1 RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install`

But how can I make these flags permanent so that I do not have to set environment variables and so it is enabled for anybody who clones the repository? I have looked and cannot find any answers.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put in the Podfile

`ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = "1"`

See https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1420